# How can I get increment value after a specific interval using for loop in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to show my output 0 to 50 after two digits interval but it's produce an infinity loop and therefore, crash my  browser. How can I solve my issue?

```
<?php

    for ($x = 0; $x < 50; $x+2) {    
        echo "The number is: $x <br>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Please see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php You never increase `$x`

Comment: `$x+2` doesn't actually CHANGE $x. it should be `$x = $x + 2` That means your $x starts at `0`, and STAYS at `0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `$x`:

```
<?php
   for ($x = 0; $x < 50; $x = $x+2) {    
      echo "The number is: $x <br>";
   }
?>
```

you could also use `$x+=2` as a shorthand instead of `$x = $x+2`

Answer (score 1):

Change the incremet to $x+=2 like:`

```
for($x=0; $x<50; $x+=2){
//do any thing...  Echo
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try with do while loop.

```
$x = 0;
do {
 echo "The number is: $x <br />";
 $x = $x + 2;
} while($x < 50);
```